# FCM give success but Notification is not received by device in Ionic V1

Tags: php, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, phonegap-pushplugin

I am using FIREBASE CLOUD MESSAGING service with my ionic product and **phonegap-plugin-push** cordova plugin to get push notification from PHP BACK END.

When I am trying to get push notification then php end is getting result with success as below.

**Sample Push Data Payload**

> {"multicast_id":8853634389214913500,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1495614850271706%39688dd8f9fd7ecd"}]}

**Technology specification :**

- cordova push notification plugin version :1.9.4
- Platform and Version: Ionic V1
- Ionic CLI version : 2.1.13
- Cordova version :  cordova --6.4.0
- Android platform for cordova :6.0.0
- Android) What device vendor I have tested : Samsung, HUWAWEI, Xiaomi
  etc.
- Sample Code that illustrates the problem as below

  **IONIC PART:**

  //Push Notification 
  if (window.cordova) {
      if (!localStorage.getItem('device_token')) {
          var apkId = 0;
          var iosId = 0;
          var options = {
              android: {
                  senderID: MY FCM SENDER ID,
                  icon: "alert",
              },
              ios: {
                  alert: "true",
                  badge: "true",
                  sound: "true"
              },
              windows: {}
          };

  ```
      //localStorage.getItem('gcmRegId')
      // initialize
      $cordovaPushV5.initialize(options).then(function () {
          // start listening for new notifications
          $cordovaPushV5.onNotification();
          // start listening for errors
          $cordovaPushV5.onError();


          // register to get registrationId
          $cordovaPushV5.register().then(function (data) {
              //alert("GCM"+data);
              // if Android device.
              if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
                  apkId = data;
              }
              // if ios device.
              if (ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
                  iosId = data;
              }
              // Updating member details with apkId or iosId
              var pushParams = {
                  'app_token': Config.appToken,
                  'device_uiu_token': device.uuid,
                  'apk_token': apkId,
                  'ios_token': iosId
              }
              $http.post(Config.apiUrl + "member/save_token", pushParams)
                  .success(function (data) {
                      if (data.status == 200) {
                          localStorage.setItem("device_token", device.uuid);

                      }
                      /* else{
                       alert("Sorry!Error occurs!");
                       } */
                  });
          })
          // Updating end.
      });

      // triggered every time notification received
      $rootScope.$on('$cordovaPushV5:notificationReceived', function (event, data) {
          alert("recieved" + JSON.stringify(data));
          // data.message,
          // data.title,
          // data.count,
          // data.sound,
          // data.image,
          // data.additionalData
      });

      // triggered every time error occurs
      $rootScope.$on('$cordovaPushV5:errorOcurred', function (event, e) {
          alert('push ERROR' + e.message);
          // e.message
      });
  ```

  // push notification end

**PHP PART:**

```
$push_title = $this->input->post('push_title');
$push_msg = $this->input->post('push_msg');
$members = $this->members_model->get_members();
$apk_tokens = array();
$ios_tokens = array();
foreach ($members as $member) {
    if ($member['apk_token'] != 0 || $member['apk_token'] != "") {
        array_push($apk_tokens, $member['apk_token']);
    }
    if ($member['ios_token'] != 0 || $member['ios_token'] != "") {
        array_push($ios_tokens, $member['ios_token']);
    }
}
//Sending the push notification using GCM.
$msg = array(
    'message' => $push_msg,
    'title' => $push_title,
    'vibrate' => 1,
    'sound' => 1,
    'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
    'smallIcon' => 'small_icon',
);

$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids' => $apk_tokens,
    'data' => $msg,
    'priority' => 'high'
);

$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: MY FCM SERVER KEY',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @KENdi - did you ever resolve this issue?  I also have success in the response but am NOT receiving the notification at all.

Comment: I have solved by checking the token size.For my case I was saving token by triming some more string due to sql field length.After increasing that token were saved correctly n worked fine! So check your registered n sending token first!         Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

If you want to show the notification on lock screen, use `notification` in `$fields`. The object requires `title` and `body` elements.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#implementing-http-connection-server-protocol

```
$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids' => $apk_tokens,
    'data' => $msg,
    'priority' => 'high',
    'notification' => array(
        'title' => 'This is title',
        'body' => 'This is body'
    )
);
```

I did not try this code, but same issue with node.js SDK has been fixed in this way.

Comment: adding Notification in array works for me. Thanks mate. +1

Answer (score 0):

As per latest update in FCM, following will be code:

```html
$curl = curl_init(); 
$msg = [
    "message" => [
          "notification" => [ 
        "title" =>  $content->title,
                "body" => $content->notification_body,
        "image" => $content->notification_image
          ],                
                "token" => $token
            ]
    ];
$data = json_encode($msg); 

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/'. $project_id .'/messages:send',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . getGoogleAccessToken($project_id),
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ),
));
    
$response = curl_exec($curl);
    
$resp = json_decode($response);

function getGoogleAccessToken($file_name) { 
    $credentialsFilePath = base_path(). "/". $file_name .".json"; //replace this with your actual path and file name
    echo "Cred_file". $credentialsFilePath;
    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig($credentialsFilePath);
    $client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging');
    $client->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
    $token = $client->getAccessToken();
    return $token['access_token'];
   }
```